# css for centering the text in center of the div

Tags: html, css

```css
.sidemenu {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 150px;
 
  height: 250px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #f9f2f2;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.menu{
  height: 45px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align:left;
  margin-left:2px;
  
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #e5e3e3 5%, #ffffff 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #e5e3e3), color-stop(1, #ffffff));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #e5e3e3 5%, #ffffff 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#e5e3e3", endColorstr="#ffffff");
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e5e3e3, ffffff);
  background-color: #e5e3e3;
  border: 1px solid #f9f2f2;
  border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="side">
                   <div class="sidemenu">
                        <div class="1 menu">
                          <a href="admin_dashboard.php" class="astext">Profile</a>
                        </div> <!--End of menu1 -->
                        <div class="2 menu">
                          <a href="clients.php" class="astext">Clients</a>
                        </div> <!--End of menu 2-->
                        <div class="3 menu">
                          <a href="employees.php" class="astext">Employees</a>
                        </div> <!--End of menu 3-->
                        <div class="menu 4">
                        <a href="admin_file_view.php" class="astext">Documents</a>
                        </div> <!--End of menu 4-->
                   </div> <!--End of side menu -->
                   </div>  <!--End of side div -->
```

I want to display the the text in vertical center of the div tag.I tried for margin-top:10px;but I cant center the text.I attached the image.The menu displayed in top left.But I want to display it in center left where I marked it in green color.
[image]

Comment: Don't you want the click event to happend on the whole button rather than just the text ?

Comment: I want to fire some action on click.

Comment: I mean, the click event will just happend on the text (`<a>` element), not the whole button that contains it (`<div>` parent element)

Comment: I want it in <a> .Is it possible to do it for div?If it is possible I will try for it.

Comment: See the answer of @MofarjulMolla. It is much better IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `line-height` equal to the height of the div.

```css
.sidemenu {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 150px;
 
  height: 250px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #f9f2f2;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.menu{
  height: 45px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align:left;
  margin-left:2px;
  line-height: 45px;   /*   <---------- Added This */
  
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #e5e3e3 5%, #ffffff 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #e5e3e3), color-stop(1, #ffffff));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #e5e3e3 5%, #ffffff 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#e5e3e3", endColorstr="#ffffff");
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e5e3e3, ffffff);
  background-color: #e5e3e3;
  border: 1px solid #f9f2f2;
  border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="side">
                   <div class="sidemenu">
                        <div class="1 menu">
                          <a href="admin_dashboard.php" class="astext">Profile</a>
                        </div> <!--End of menu1 -->
                        <div class="2 menu">
                          <a href="clients.php" class="astext">Clients</a>
                        </div> <!--End of menu 2-->
                        <div class="3 menu">
                          <a href="employees.php" class="astext">Employees</a>
                        </div> <!--End of menu 3-->
                        <div class="menu 4">
                        <a href="admin_file_view.php" class="astext">Documents</a>
                        </div> <!--End of menu 4-->
                   </div> <!--End of side menu -->
                   </div>  <!--End of side div -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution will be setting the line height for menu class like below:

```
.menu a{line-height:45px;}
```

else you can display that as table cell using css display property and defining the vertical-align center.

Comment: Why did you use 24px?

Comment: Sorry ! it should be the value of height. in this case its 45px.

`.menu a{line-height:45px;}`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
.menu a{line-height:40px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add an line-height to your link and set him to display inline-block like:

```
.menu a {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pik_at/dz07qrq8/

Comment: You don´t need `display: inline-block;` and the parent has `height: 45px;` so you don´t need it either.

Comment: Better to set on inline-block or the link will be only triggering on text and not on the button himself, obviously he can adapt like he want to

Answer (score 1):

Add a

```
a.astext {
  line-height:2.5em;
}
```

to your code it works fine.

```css
.sidemenu {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 150px;
 
  height: 250px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #f9f2f2;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.menu{
  height: 45px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align:left;
  margin-left:2px;
  
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #e5e3e3 5%, #ffffff 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #e5e3e3), color-stop(1, #ffffff));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #e5e3e3 5%, #ffffff 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#e5e3e3", endColorstr="#ffffff");
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e5e3e3, ffffff);
  background-color: #e5e3e3;
  border: 1px solid #f9f2f2;
  border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px 7px;
}
a.astext
{
line-height:2.5em;}
```

```html
<div class="side">
                   <div class="sidemenu">
                        <div class="1 menu">
                          <a href="admin_dashboard.php" class="astext">Profile</a>
                        </div> <!--End of menu1 -->
                        <div class="2 menu">
                          <a href="clients.php" class="astext">Clients</a>
                        </div> <!--End of menu 2-->
                        <div class="3 menu">
                          <a href="employees.php" class="astext">Employees</a>
                        </div> <!--End of menu 3-->
                        <div class="menu 4">
                        <a href="admin_file_view.php" class="astext">Documents</a>
                        </div> <!--End of menu 4-->
                   </div> <!--End of side menu -->
                   </div>  <!--End of side div -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use :

```
.menu {
    display: table
}
.menu a {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0rr7018r/)**

Comment: "I want to display the the text in vertical center"

Comment: I found this answer much better for three things : it does not require to "duplicate" the height of the parent (this way, you can change the height of the parent without having to change anything on the link element), then the `<a>` element will take the whole height of the `<div>`, which I think is more suitable for a button, and then, you can have text on multiple lines still centered (which is not the case when using `line-height`)

Answer (score 1):

set the position of .menu to relative and position of .astext absolute with margin-top 10px

```
.menu{
  height: 45px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align:left;
  margin-left:2px;
  ...
  position:relative;
}


.menu a.astext{
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58jjsgmg/)